# Asymptotic behaviour of sum over the inverse japanese symbol

Tags: real-analysis, summation, asymptotics

I am interested in the asymptotic behavior of the sum
$$\sum_{m=1}^M\frac{1}{\sqrt{m^2+\omega}}$$
for $1>\omega>0$ in the Limit $M\to\infty$ up to order $\mathcal{O}(M^{-1})$.

The first thing I did was splitting the sum as follows:

$$\sum_{m=1}^M\frac{1}{\sqrt{m^2+\omega}}=\sum_{m=1}^M\frac{1}{m}+\sum_{m=1}^M\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{m^2+\omega}}-\frac{1}{m}\right)$$

For the first sum I use the Euler approximation to get
$$\sum_{m=1}^M\frac{1}{m}=\log(M)+\gamma_E+\mathcal{O}(M^{-1}).$$

Now I suspect that the remainder goes like
$$\sum_{m=1}^M\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{m^2+\omega}}-\frac{1}{m}\right)=c(\omega)+\mathcal{O}(M^{-1}).$$

The question is, how can I explicitly compute $c(\omega)$?

Comment: "Inverse japanese symbol"??

Comment: In the literature $<x>=\sqrt{x^2+1}$ is often called the japanese symbol or japanese bracket. $\sqrt{m^2+\omega}$ is sort of a generalized japanese symbol.

Comment: In *what* literature? I've never seen such a thing and I thought I knew quite some odd things. Perhaps in the *japanese* mathematical literature?

Comment: In mathematical physics, especially, when one considers the Dirac operator, one often encounters this symbol, e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.5779 . In fact the name goes back to Kato I think.

Comment: I agree that the terminology is standard in many areas of mathematics ( here's an example of Terry Tao using it: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/04/30/245c-notes-4-sobolev-spaces/ ). This aside, I think it is better to adapt the proof of the formula $\sum_1^N \frac1n = \log n+\gamma + O(N^{-1})$ rather than using the result itself. Applying the Abel summation formula (aka Euler-Mclaurin) one gets (HTH) $$\sum_{n\le x} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+m^2}} = 
\frac{[x]}{\sqrt{x^2+m^2} }+ \int_1^x \frac{[t]t}{(t^2+m^2)^\frac32}\, dt.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we exploit:

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+\omega}}-\frac{1}{x}\right)=-1+J_0(s\sqrt{\omega})=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{s^{2n}\omega^n(-1)^n}{4^nn!^2} \tag{1}$$
we have:

> $$ c(\omega)-\gamma = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{J_0(s\sqrt{\omega})-1}{e^s-1}\,ds. \tag{2} $$

Comment: Wonderful trick! That's an expression with that I can work way better.

Comment: Since $\int_0^\infty\frac{s^{2n}}{e^s-1}\,\mathrm{d}s=(2n)!\zeta(2n+1)$, applying the series in $(1)$ to the integral in $(2)$ matches the series in $(4)$ of my answer (if you remove the acceleration I used with $\zeta(2n+1)-1$).

Answer (score 4):

The Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula applied to the power series in $\frac1m$ yields

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \sum_{m=1}^M\frac1{\sqrt{m^2+\omega}}
> &=\log(M)+c(\omega)+\frac1{2M}+\frac{3\omega-1}{12M^2}-\frac\omega{4M^3}\\
> &+\frac{4+60\omega-45\omega^2}{480M^4}+\frac{3\omega^2}{M^5}+O\!\left(\frac1{M^6}\right)\tag{1}
> \end{align}
> $$

and
$$
\sum_{m=1}^M\frac1m
=\log(M)+\gamma+\frac1{2M}-\frac1{12M^2}+\frac1{120M^4}+O\!\left(\frac1{M^6}\right)\tag{2}
$$
Note that as $\omega\to0$, $(1)\to(2)$, as long as $c(\omega)\to\gamma$.

Subtracting $(2)$ from $(1)$ and letting $M\to\infty$, we get
$$
c(\omega)-\gamma
=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{\sqrt{m^2+\omega}}-\frac1m\right)\tag{3}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
c(\omega)
&=\gamma+\sum_{m=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{\sqrt{m^2+\omega}}-\frac1m\right)\\
&=\gamma+\frac1{\sqrt{1+\omega}}-1+\sum_{m=2}^\infty\left(\frac1{\sqrt{m^2+\omega}}-\frac1m\right)\\
&=\gamma+\frac1{\sqrt{1+\omega}}-1+\sum_{m=2}^\infty\frac1m\sum_{k=1}^\infty\binom{2k}{k}\left(-\frac\omega{4m^2}\right)^k\\
&=\gamma+\frac1{\sqrt{1+\omega}}-1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(-\frac\omega4\right)^k\binom{2k}{k}\underbrace{(\zeta(2k+1)-1)}_{\sim2^{-2k-1}}\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
That is,

> $$
> c(\omega)=\gamma+\frac1{\sqrt{1+\omega}}-1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(-\frac\omega4\right)^k\binom{2k}{k}(\zeta(2k+1)-1)\tag{5}
> $$

The absolute value of the coefficient of $\omega^k$ in the summation is $\,\sim\!\frac1{4^k\sqrt{4\pi k}}$, so the sum converges for $\left|\omega\right|\lt4$. Therefore, $\lim\limits_{\omega\to0}c(\omega)=\gamma$, as required above.

---

Note that if we incorporate $\frac1{\sqrt{1+\omega}}-1$ into the summation in $(4)$ and move $\gamma$ to the right side, we get
$$
c(\omega)-\gamma=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(-\frac\omega4\right)^k\binom{2k}{k}\zeta(2k+1)\tag{6}
$$
which matches formula $(1)$ from Jack D'Aurizio's answer applied to the integral in $(2)$ from Jack D'Aurizio's answer. However, $(6)$ only converges for $-1\lt\omega\le1$.

---

Here is a plot of $c(\omega)$ for $0\le\omega\le1$:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you use the Riemann integral trick, one gets: $$\sum_{m=1}^M\frac{1}{\sqrt{m^2+\omega}} \sim \ln\frac{2M}{1+\sqrt{\omega+1}}+\frac{1}{4}\frac{\omega}{M^2}+\mathcal{O}(\frac{\omega^2}{M^4})$$

To see how well the RHS function (which let us call it $fa(M)$, as the asymptotic form of the sum) approximates the sum, here is the ratio of the sum to its asymptotic (?) formula (ie, the RHS of our equation):
[image]

($N$ in the figure is our $M$). The red line is a fit to the ratio ($\omega=0.43$) .

Hope this helps you a bit.

Added note: if in the Riemann sum we sum up the trapezes (with areas slightly bigger than the area under the curve) instead of rectangles, the new formula (with absolute error almost an order of magnitude less) reads now: 
 $$\sum_{m=1}^M\frac{1}{\sqrt{m^2+\omega}} \sim \ln\frac{2M}{1+\sqrt{\omega+1}}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\omega+1}} + \frac{1}{2M} + \frac{1}{4}\frac{\omega}{M^2}+\mathcal{O}(\frac{\omega}{M^3})$$

Comment: i guess u have to replace $N\rightarrow M$ in your formula ?

Comment: @tired: corrected now, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: nice, now i'm happy to upvote. well done!

Comment: Note that for $\omega=0$, this gives $$\sum_{m=1}^M\frac1m\sim\log(M)+O\!\left(\frac0{M^4}\right)$$ That is, this answer is only significant to $\log(M)$. The constant is in error and the other terms are in error by $O\!\left(\frac1M\right)$

Comment: @robjohn: well, i did not claim i got an asymptotic expression to the sum. Just a useful approximation of it to a good accuracy. I think it can be improved (the accuracy) by using trapezoidal sums instead of rectangles as I did for the Riemann sum.  Would you do a similar plot as I did to see how well your formula approximates the true value of the sum?

Comment: @Chip: The error of your approximation is shown in [this plot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Aqcdk.png). It is tending toward $\log\left(\frac2{1+\sqrt{1.43}}\right)-c(0.43)=-0.465796758468$ due to the wrong constant. It also has an error of $O\!\left(\frac1M\right)$, not $O\!\left(\frac1{M^4}\right)$. The error of my approximation is shown in [this plot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kkl8V.png).

Comment: @robjohn: thanks for the graphs. I noticed that if in the Riemann sum I sum up trapezes under the curve $1/\sqrt{x^2+\omega}$ instead of rectangles as I did in my answer, I get two extra terms $0.5*(1/\sqrt{\omega+1}+1/M)$. The modulus of the absolute error with this addition can be seen here http://i.stack.imgur.com/2d63K.png.